# selenium + python: what dictates the speed of send_keys? i want to speed it up

Tags: python, performance, selenium

i have a python script that, if i run it on my desktop, it runs very fast. it types a whole paragraph in a second or less. however, if i run this same python script on a virtual machine with the same environment etc it will type the paragraph about as fast as a normal person. what determines the speed of send_keys? why would the virtual machine type it so much slower?

all computers and virtual machines in this situation are running windows 7, python32, and the latest selenium.

Comment: It would simply have to do with the stats of the VM.  Remember that there is a lot more processing going on with a virtual machine.  It has nothing to do with the selenium code.

Comment: Does the both OS are same? as you said same environment then I'm presuming that OS is windows 7 on each case and you are running 32 bit architecture. In a general case virtual machines take a huge amount of memory and processor. So while running on virtual machine you are not getting the full resource, you are only getting a share of your resource. That might be the reason.

Comment: just for fun, i ran it on an intel I7 laptop with 8gb ram and it ran about as fast as the VMs. my desktop at home isn't anything super special but i guess it handles this type of stuff extremely well.

Comment: What browser are we talking about?

Comment: Also are the browser, selenium version the same across all platforms? Are you running it locally on the Mac machine as compared to running it remotely on the VM and ur home pc?